# Why when using editor script with handles with DrawSolidArc it's not drawing any arc over the object?

Tags: unity, c#

This is the editor script is in the Assets/Editor

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

[CustomEditor(typeof(DrawSolidArc))]
public class DrawSolidArcEditor : Editor
{
    public float arrowSize = 1;

    void OnSceneGUI()
    {
        DrawSolidArc t = target as DrawSolidArc;

        Handles.color = Color.blue;
        Handles.Label(t.transform.position + Vector3.up * 2,
                             t.transform.position.ToString() + "\nShieldArea: " +
                             t.shieldArea.ToString());

        Handles.BeginGUI();
        GUILayout.BeginArea(new Rect(Screen.width - 100, Screen.height - 80, 90, 50));

        if (GUILayout.Button("Reset Area"))
            t.shieldArea = 5;

        GUILayout.EndArea();
        Handles.EndGUI();

        Handles.color = new Color(1, 1, 1, 0.2f);
        Handles.DrawSolidArc(t.transform.position, t.transform.up, -t.transform.right,
                                180, t.shieldArea);

        Handles.color = Color.white;
        t.shieldArea = Handles.ScaleValueHandle(t.shieldArea,
                        t.transform.position + t.transform.forward * t.shieldArea,
                        t.transform.rotation, 1, Handles.ConeHandleCap, 1);
    }
}
```

And the mono script for example this script is attached to a simple 3d cube :

```
using UnityEngine;

[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class DrawSolidArc : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float shieldArea = 5;
}
```

but there is nothing around the cube. not also near it nothing.
it should draw arch in the editor.

Later I want to be able to use the mouse with a click down and drag to be able to change the arc size but for not it's not drawing any arc.

I took the example from the unity official docs :

https://docs.unity3d.com/540/Documentation/ScriptReference/Handles.DrawSolidArc.html

I noticed now also for example that I don't see the gui button in the inspector of the object that the mono script is attached to :

```
if (GUILayout.Button("Reset Area"))
```

not sure what's wrong with the editor script.

This is working. I still wonder why the unity docs example didn't work but this is working and I don't need the editor script. The problem with this script is that I must to turn on the Gizmos in the editor and I don't want to make it turned on all the time. So it's working but not as I wanted.

I want to draw the arc without the gizmos.

```
using UnityEngine;

[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class DrawSolidArc : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Vector3 offset = Vector3.one;
    public float fieldOfViewAngle = 20;
    public float viewDistance = 4;
    public bool usePhysics2D = false;

    public void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        DrawLineOfSight(this.transform, offset, fieldOfViewAngle, viewDistance, usePhysics2D);
    }
    public static void DrawLineOfSight(Transform transform, Vector3 positionOffset, float fieldOfViewAngle, float viewDistance, bool usePhysics2D)
    {
#if UNITY_EDITOR
        var oldColor = UnityEditor.Handles.color;
        var color = Color.yellow;
        color.a = 0.1f;
        UnityEditor.Handles.color = color;
        var halfFOV = fieldOfViewAngle * 0.5f;
        var beginDirection = Quaternion.AngleAxis(-halfFOV, (usePhysics2D ? Vector3.forward : Vector3.up)) * (usePhysics2D ? transform.up : transform.forward);
        UnityEditor.Handles.DrawSolidArc(transform.TransformPoint(positionOffset), (usePhysics2D ? transform.forward : transform.up), beginDirection, fieldOfViewAngle, viewDistance);
        UnityEditor.Handles.color = oldColor;
#endif
    }
}
```

Comment: Are your Gizmos by any chance disabled? Copy pasted the script and it shows up right in the scene view when you select the cube. Button is missing though

Comment: @Zibelas Right I found that the problem is that the Gizmos in the editor was disabled. but I want to do it without the Gizmos and the main goal is to be able to use the cone to set a view field so if any object get into the view field of the cone detect it.